# Django order foreign key items in queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am using Django models abstract base class to generate my website menus from the db. My models look like this:

```
# ABSTRACT MENU 
class Menu(models.Model):
    position = models.IntegerField("Item Position", max_length=2, unique=False)
    title_en = models.CharField("Title (English)", max_length=50)
    title_es = models.CharField("Titulo (Español)", max_length=50)
    url_en = models.URLField("url (English)")
    url_es = models.URLField("url (Español)")       

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title_en

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# top (main) menu ---> inherits from MENU
class MainMenu(Menu):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Menu Items"  

# submenu - for drop downs ---> inherits from MENU
class SubMenu(Menu):
    main_menu = models.ForeignKey(MainMenu, null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Sub Menu Items"
```

Then for the menus I do this:

```
menu_items = MainMenu.objects.all().select_related().order_by('position')
```

This is fine, and generates the main menu items ordered by position. However, the submenu items are not ordered. How can I make sure that the submenu items are ordered by position too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [defining the order in your model's `Meta` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering)?  As long as you are okay with `position` being the default order in every case it's not explicitly overridden (which can have performance impacts for large queries) that should remove the need to use .order_by() at all.  I haven't tried this for your specific case, though, so let me know if it doesn't work.

Edit: also consider looking at [order_with_respect_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to) for related models